# $\text{Coker}(f),\text{Coker}(g)$ projective modules $\Rightarrow$ $\text{Coker}(gf)$ projective

Tags: modules, projective-module

Let $\textbf{Ch}_R$ the category of chain complexes of $R-$modules ($R$ is an associative ring with unit). I want to prove that this cat. satisfies the model category axioms. In particular we want to consider a particular "class" of maps in $\textbf{Ch}_R$, called cofibration, i.e. a an arrow $f$ s.t. for each $k\geq 0$, $f_k: M_k \to N_k$ is a monomorphism with a projective $R-$module as its cokernel.

**AIM:** the aim is to prove that the composition of two cofibrations is again a cofibration.

**MY ATTEMPT:** we just work in a fixed degree, hence $f \colon M_k \to N_k$ and $g\colon N_k \to Z_k$. the composition is clearly a monomorphism, but I've some problem in proving that $\text{coker}(gf)$ is projective. My idea was to using this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1113704/162105), but I cannot manage to get the s.e.s of cokernels. The first arrow seems to be $g$, but then I don't know what to put in the other two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1113704/162105) gives you that if you have to monomorphisms $f\colon: M \to N$ and $g\colon N \to Z$, then there is a short exact sequence
$$ 0\to \operatorname{coker} f \to \operatorname{coker} gf \to \operatorname{coker} g \to 0.$$
Now if $\operatorname{coker} f$ and $\operatorname{coker} g$ both are projective, then certainly so is $\operatorname{coker} gf$.